# "In how many ways can Horatio give M&M's to three kids? (M&M's come in red, yellow, green, brown, and tan.)"

Tags: combinatorics

The question asks me for the amount of ways someone can give M&M's to three kids, the answer is 125 (5x5x5), but I don't understand why. I thought it would be 5 * 3, as there are 5 different ways he can give M&M's to each kid.

Comment: Aren't there _blue_  and _black_ M&Ms?

Comment: They're asking about the combinations, like (red,red,red), (red,red,blue), and so on.  Use the multiplication principle.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel The colors in the question correspond to M&Ms from my childhood. I suppose the question came from a very old book.

Answer (score 0):

There are $5$ ways to give an M&M to each kid. The children are distinct so we will use the multiplication principle. For each choice of which M&M we give the first 2 kids, there are 5 choices for the third kid. So the number of ways is 5 multiplied by the number of ways to give M&Ms to 2 kids. Similarly, we get $5\times5\times5=125$.